# C# Run a method of object in an ArrayList

Tags: c#

I have bulb.cs in a directory:

```
class Bulb{
  private state = 0;
  public void printState(){
    Console.Writeln("State = " + state);
  }
}
```

I am using it in main.cs in a class called MainClass:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

class MainClass {
  private ArrayList bulbs = new ArrayList();

  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    MainClass m = new MainClass();
    m.beginSimulation();
  }
  public void beginSimulation(){
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
       bulbs.Add(new Bulb());
    }
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
       bulbs[i].printState();
    }
  }
}
```

When I run main.cs in repl.it I get this error:

mcs -out:main.exe bulb.cs main.cs
main.cs(16,17): error CS1061: Type `object' does not contain a definition for` printState' and no extension method `printState' of type` object' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
/usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings
compiler exit status 1

The "main.cs(16,17)" is referring to the line "bulbs[i].printState();".

In Java you could do "bulbs.get(i).printState() and it would execute the method.  In C# I can't figure it out and I have to use ArrayList instead of List to do this.

I know you can use

```
foreach(Bulb l in bulbs){
  l.printState();
}
```

But I don't get why you can't access the method by the index like the documentation says that you can: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist.item?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: If you are learning C#, please use a modern, good quality resource. You are not getting your money's worth out of it right now.

Comment: *In Java you could do* - that's because in Java an ArrayList<E> is more like C#'s List<T>. Do not assume that class x in java and class x in c# are the same thing just because they have the same name. C# ArrayList is an ancient class more like a java Vector

Answer (score 3):

Most importantly, no one uses `ArrayList` anymore. It is not strongly typed, which is the reason you are getting this error.

You can:

1. Switch to a strongly typed generic collection like `List<T>` which will get rid of this error among other great benefits.
2. The downcast you are missing is needed here.

   ```
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
       ((Bulb)bulbs[i]).printState();
    }
   ```

The reason why `foreach()` works is because the compiler is implicitly downcasting for you given the loop variable declaration of `Bulb i`.

Comment: "It is not strongly typed" - That's not entirely accurate. A more accurate description would be that it can only hold references of type "object" which means that before you can use the references it holds you need to cast them back to their original types (which means unboxing, if the original type is a value type). IIRC, Before generics (meaning, before .Net 2.0), that was the only dynamic sized collection. That being said, it is out dated and shouldn't be used in modern .net code.